# What could cause extreme gravitational effects to earth without destroying the planet outright?

Tags: gravity, astronomy, geology

What could cause extreme gravitational effects to earth without destroying the planet outright?  I've thought about the effect of a a black hole but don't know enough about them.  In this setting the "gravitational effect" along with another force (say, nuclear detonation) will warp and or tear near space. Any ideas?

Comment: This could use additional details.  What do you want to happen?  What were you thinking would make that happen?  When I read this, I wonder "a significant gravitational effect" on what?  The answers seem to be assuming the Earth.  If so, what do you want the effect on Earth to be?  Higher tides?  Stripped of its atmosphere?  Converted into rubble?  An impact crater?

Comment: The size doesn't really matter all that much. If it's a 1-atom thick hollow shell (ok, that's impossible, but you get the point) it will have pretty much no effect (also depends on distance, as others have mentioned. "Very close" doesn't really mean anyhing). If it's a black hole with a jupiter-sized event horizon it will have a really big effect.

Comment: How close? it's important to define what you mean by "close", "significant", and "huge". Also, this situation is somewhat unlikely considering that Jupiter tends to shield Earth from large objects coming our way.

Comment: That's not a meteor. That's a planet.

Comment: By the time it enters the solar system nobody will survive, no matter what.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to downvote this. This question at present simply isn't meaningfully answerable, and frankly it feels like a random idea more than a thought-through question that you have tried to answer yourself first. As already pointed out by others, at the very least, you will have to define what you mean by "close", "very close", "significant", and answer the question "close to what?". It would also help if you define "size"; are you talking about mass, volume, diameter, or what? If not mass, then what is its average density? That's just what I can think of right now that's missing.

Comment: This is not a question answerable: First of all it is not a Meteor (Jupiter sized bodies are massive enough to be spherical and thus are Planet(oids), even if on excentric tracks or a "free Planet"). Then "close" in astronomical terms can be anything from "a few kpc" over "1 pc" to "1 ly" to "1 AU" and "distance to the moon". Very close is even more vague. Then, What is significant? Just taking Jupiter and placing him where Mars used to be would catapult earth either out of the solar system or into the sun, depending on the timing.

Answer (score 7):

A "meteor" refers to something that is actually entering the Earth's atmosphere.  As the size of this object is so much larger than Earth, the Earth would essentially be a "meteor" entering the atmosphere of this monstrous rogue planet.

The Earth's atmosphere would become a firestorm and be stripped away.  The crust of the planet would then likely become molten and also flow away until the entire planet exploded, possibly upon impact, depending on the surface.

So the gravitation effect would be incredibly strong, but would really not be at the top of the list of bad things happening that day.

Comment: Thanks Michael, so how close would a jupiter sized body have to come to earth to affect gravity but not give us scorched earth - and then if it's not called a meteor at that point, would you please tell me the correct term?

Comment: "Rogue planet" or "failed star" might be a better descriptor.  "Asteroid" may be the word you meant in your question.  Jupiter technically has a gravitational effect upon the earth, but the Sun's and the Moon's are much stronger because of size and proximity.  As Cyrus's answer stated, if this object entered the inner solar system, it would likely knock everything out of their nearly circular orbits, either into major elliptical orbits or knocking them out of the system entirely.

Comment: Thanks to the slingshot effect even if it didn't get close enough to kill everyone with tidal forces we'd start to get worried as the sun slowly started to appear larger.

Comment: CandiedOrange, could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @Tenacity sure.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with the question of scale. [Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) is about 10.5 times the diameter of Earth, and about 317 times [Earth's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) mass. Jupiter outweighs all the other stuff orbiting the sun, combined. A description of the Solar System as "A star, one giant planet and a lot of debris" is fairly accurate if uncomplimentary to the other seven planets.

The only way that the real Jupiter's orbit, or Earth's orbit, can change enough to bring them close together is for some massive body from outside the Solar System to intrude and its gravity to "perturb" the orbits of the planets (and asteroids, comets, etc.). So we might as well assume that this outside body, which we'll call "neo-Jupiter" is what's encountering Earth. We'll claim it is similar enough to Jupiter not to make a difference, within the precision of this answer. It is what's known as a "[rogue planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)". We're pretty sure these exist, although our ability to detect them is very limited, and our estimates of how many there are out there are vague, at best.

If it passes through the solar system without hitting anything important and without coming close to Earth, nothing very major happens. The year probably changes length slightly, lots of astronomical calculations have to be redone, the climate may alter a little because the Earth's orbit has changed, but there's no apocalypse. "Close" in these terms is about an Astronomical Unit, the average distance between the Earth and the Sun, which is a convenient yardstick for measuring distances to planets.

If neo-Jupiter comes closer than that, we may well have big trouble. The Earth's orbit will change, as will the Moon's. The effects of this on the climate are likely to be severe or catastrophic, as the Earth's orbit will become less circular and more elliptical. So the Earth's minimum distance from the Sun may decrease, meaning it gets hotter at that time of the (different-length) year, potentially a *lot* hotter. Alternatively, the Earth's maximum distance from the sun may increase, meaning - as you might guess - it gets colder at that time of year. It might be a *lot* colder. If we're unlucky, both effects happen.

These effects have the potential to make Earth uninhabitable, and there really isn't anything we could do about it. We might, with years of advance warning, and an unusual lack of denial by politicians, manage to do something about asteroids with a mass of a few thousand to a few million tons. Our ability to move the Earth out of the way is non-existent, nil, nada, zero. Deflecting neo-Jupiter would be much harder. An ant trying to stop an express train with its own muscles would have more nearly adequate force.

For shorter encounter distances between Earth and neo-Jupiter, the effects get more drastic. Earth might be flung into the Sun, or ejected from the Solar System entirely. At that point, a relatively painless death would be the limit of our hopes.

If Earth collides with Neo-Jupiter, then I refer you to Michael Richardson's answer. The [Roche Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) doesn't come into it, since the radius from Neo-Jupiter at which Earth falls apart is rather smaller than that of Neo-Jupiter, so the collision happens first.

One possible solution to the [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) is that massive rogue planets are actually fairly common, but the Solar System been unusually lucky in not having a close encounter with one for the last four billion years.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very vague question. If by close you mean a lightyear or two, there would be little effect. If it passed inside Mars orbit, it would probably destabilize all the inner planets' orbits. If it passed between the Earth and moon, well, they wouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: Just to have it said: Jupiter has an equatorial radius of just under 71.5 Mm (with significant flattening due to its high rate of rotation). The distance from the Earth to the Moon is about 400 Mm. So if magically placed between the Earth and the Moon in such a way that all three survive and remain in place, Jupiter would straddle about 1/6 of the distance from the Earth to the Moon. Which, coincidentally, is about the ratio of the Moon's surface gravity to that of the Earth... and is totally unrelated.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I beg to differ! If you place Jupiter between them, Earth and Moon would be ground to dust because no Planetoid can survice inside the Roche limit, and the Roche limit of Jupiter is ~1,733 Mm for a fully fluid object and ~895 Mm for solid bodies.

Comment: @Trish You are not differing at all! Notice the part of my comment that says "if magically placed ... in such a way that all three survive and remain in place"? I specifically *avoided* the pesky detail of real-world physics, in order to point out the relative size of Jupiter to the Earth-Moon system.

Answer (score 0):

Fun things that can happen just because of gravity:

Suppose we wanted to have a little fun with the solar system but without actually touching it.  The general term for this is *perturb* but that's dull so let's talk about the kinds with fun names.

**Slingshot**

This gravitational effect is how voyager I and II got where they are today.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTIGOe5ckj0) shows the paths.  I recommend you watch it with the sound off.  Blech.

If you know anything about conservation of energy you may be asking where the energy to fling those spacecraft around came from.  Yep we slowed the planets down just to give our craft a speed boost.  Doubt it'll send Jupiter hurling towards us any time soon.  But we did perturb it.  Just not much.  Jupiter is freakin big.

It works like being double bounced on a trampoline or rolling around on the same bed.  You don't have to touch the other person to feel their energy.

If something the size of jupiter went whizzing by the earth it could easily send us off in some direction that wouldn't be good for our health, without even touching us.

Which is a shame because the movie version of this disaster would have the most boring special effects ever.  No explosions.  Phooey.

**Horseshoe orbits**

If somehow we're lucky enough to not get flung out of the goldilocks zone and actually remain in a stable orbit something as weird as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsHBE3DWCP4) might start happening.

A horseshoe orbit is really the slingshot effect done in a stable way.  Two bodies interact gravitationally and exchange momentum.  One ends up in a more energetic orbit. The other ends up in a less energetic orbit.  This could really make time fly as the length of our year would suddenly change.  Given enough time they run into each other again and do the swap again.  Now it seems to take forever to get to christmas.

What would make it worse of course is if we discovered intelligent alien life on this planet and the only message it sent was, *"Does this bug you?  I'm not touching you".*

Comment: The planetX link is a crank channel, not real information. The (real) paper on a possible large mass affecting the orbits of high-ecentricity TNO’s is over hyped, didn’t *prove* anything, and neglects other ideas like how these orbits self-organize without any such help needed.

Comment: Here’s a [real report](http://www.seti.org/weeky-lecture/bizarre-orbits-minor-planets-beyond-neptune) from astronomers studying the data. See what’s really been observed and a less-hyped explaination.

Comment: @JDługosz I presume TNO is Trans-Neptunian Object. TNO is an over-used acronym. Trust No One, Thai National Observatory trained nonchalantly on a Trans-Neptunian Object. Sorry! I couldn't resist the temptation.

Comment: @JDługosz fine.

Comment: Thanks JDlugosz, watching the outer solar system video now - interesting